# Calculating realistic box-shadow with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a book library webapp with books draggable between the shelves.

Applying `box-shadow` to books made them look slightly more realistic but I wondered if I can go further and dynamically calculate `box-shadow` values for every book by its position relative to a single chosen “light source” point, like a game engine would do.

Thus, if we choose top center point to be the light source, a book on the left will have a left bottom shadow, and a book on the right will have a right bottom shadow. Books at the bottom would get shadows of larger height, et cetera. We might need to specify depth (z-coordinate) for the light source as well as its position.

While `box-shadow` doesn't allow for complex realistic shadows, I suspect it would be more than enough to adjust shadow size and angle with regards to their position for rectangular objects such as books to make them a lot more realistic.

Has anyone already looked into implementing this in JavaScript? Are you aware of any open source libraries that calculate `box-shadow` values with regards to a specific light source point? If not, is the idea inherently wrong in some way I haven't thought of, or is it that nobody has tried just this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bloke called Jeff Pamer made an experiment about this

requires jQuery and jQuery UI Draggable ([see demo](http://www.wewillbeok.com/likeacastshadow/))

**your html:**

```
<div id="light_source">Light Source<br />(drag me)</div>
<div id="div1" class="needs_shadow">(drag me)</div>
<div id="div2" class="needs_shadow">(drag me)</div>
```

**your JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").draggable({
    drag: function() { make_shade() }
  });
  make_shade();  
});

function make_shade() {
  var light = $("div#light_source");
  var light_pos = light.position();
  var light_x = light_pos.left + (light.width() / 2);
  var light_y = light_pos.top + (light.height() / 2);

  $(".needs_shadow").each(function() {
    var div1 = $(this);
    var div1_pos = div1.position();

    var div_x = div1_pos.left + (div1.width() / 2);
    var div_y = div1_pos.top + (div1.height() / 2);

    var left_diff = light_x - div_x;
    var top_diff = light_y - div_y;

    var left = (left_diff / 10) * -1;
    var top = (top_diff / 10) * -1;

    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(left_diff, 2) + Math.pow(top_diff, 2));
    distance = distance / 10;

    shadow_style = left + "px " + top + "px " + distance + "px #3f3f3f";
    div1.css("-moz-box-shadow", shadow_style);
    div1.css("-webkit-box-shadow", shadow_style);
    div1.css("box-shadow", shadow_style);
  });
}
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged jQuery!

Comment: No, but it is tagged "javascript-library" of which jQuery is an excellent one.

Comment: O, I did oversee this tag :D .

Comment: Great find! This is just what I was looking for, and the code is formatted so it is easy to follow. I guess I'll look into this solution more carefully in a few days, and if I turn it into something useful, I'll open source it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my try in a comment, but maybe I'll get upvotes so I'll write it in a answer, too. :D .

```
var source = [0, 0], faktor = [10, 20];
```

The source is where the light should be, the faktor is the faktor for the shadows ([0] for shadow position, [1] for blur).

```
function addShadows() {
    var i, j, position, sizeE, distance; for(i=0,j=arguments.length;i<j;++i) {
        position = offset(arguments[i]); // Get position from element

        sizeE = size(arguments[i]); // Get width and height from element

        distance = parseInt(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(position[0] + sizeE[0] / 2 - source[0], 2) + Math.pow(position[1] + sizeE[1] / 2 - source[1], 2))) / faktor[1]; // calculate a distance for bluring (middle of element to source)

        arguments[i].style.cssText += 'box-shadow: ' + ((position[0] + sizeE[0] - source[0]) / faktor[0]) + 'px ' + ((position[1] + sizeE[1] - source[1]) / faktor[0]) + 'px ' + distance + 'px #555555'; // add the shadow
    }
}
```

The function `addShadows` will add shadows to all parameters.

```
function getStyle(element, attribut) {
    var style;

    if(window.getComputedStyle) {
        style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    } else {
        style = element.currentStyle;
    }

    return style[attribut];
}
function offset(element) {
    var pos = [parseInt(getStyle(element, 'border-top')), parseInt(getStyle(element, 'border-top'))];

    while(element !== null) {
        pos[0] += element.offsetLeft;
        pos[1] += element.offsetTop;

        element = element.offsetParent;
    }

    return pos;
}
function size(element) {
    return [element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight];
}
function id(idE) {
    return document.getElementById(idE);
}
```

The four functions above are just helper functions.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5UbL/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'll look into it as soon as I get home.

Comment: I just saw the demo! It certainly looks cool but Jeff's code is easier to read so I'm accepting it as the answer instead. I'll look both into your and Jeff's solution when writing code for my app, and if I manage to turn it into something useful, I'll definitely open source it. Thanks!